# Xamarin MvvmCross Set Text through Command

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

Hi i'm learning MvvmCross with Xamarin. I want to set the value of the EdiText and put it in the TextView when i click a button through a command in a PLC project. But i need some help with the command
i think may be something like `_description = Description` but is not working.

this is what i got

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
          private string _description;

    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public MvxCommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new MvxCommand(SetValueCommand);
    }

    private void SetValueCommand()
    {
        // i don`t know how to express it 
    }
}
```

this is my axml

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mytextview"
    android:text=""
    />

<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    app:MvxBind="Text MyDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    android:text="Set Data"
    app:MvxBind="Click ClearCommand"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: You are binding Text to MyDescription which doesn't seem to exist in your sample code. Also in the `SetValueCommand` you can just assign `Description` to whatever you want.  Like `Description = "I like cheese";`

Answer (score 1):

Hi I recommended to you read about in the documentation exist 2 diferents ways to bind  with MVVMCross

Tibet and Rio, actually you are using Tibet, but also you can use the Rio method, the rio method you can reduce the code in less lines of code.

You can use Rio when you have a small ViewModels like I show you in the next example.

example

```
//Rio Method
public class MathsViewModel
{
  public readonly INC<double> SubTotal = new NC<double>();
  public readonly INC<double> Percent = new NC<double>();

  public void Calculate()
  {
    Total.Value = SubTotal.Value * Percent.Value;
  }

  public readonly INC<double> Total = new NC<double>();
}
```

And now the same code using Tibet

```
//Tibet method
public class MathsViewModel
{ 
 private double _subTotal;
 public double SubTotal
 {
    get => _subTotal;
    set => SetProperty(ref _subTotal, value);
 } 

 private double _percent;
 public double Percent
 {
    get => _percent;
    set => SetProperty(ref _percent, value);
 }

 private ICommand _calculateCommand;
 public ICommand CalculateCommand;
 {
    get 
    {
        _calculateCommand = _calculateCommand ?? new MvxCommand(Calculate);
        return _calculateCommand;
    }
 }

 private void Calculate()
 {
    Total = SubTotal * Percent;
 }    

 private double _total;
 public double Total
 {
    get => _total;
    set => SetProperty(ref _total, value);
 }
}
```

For more details read the documentations about Rio.

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding

Both are valid types of bind with mvvmcross, the Tibet method that are you applying in your code is fine works perfect.

I bring you this one so you can read about it and expand your knowledge.

I would use Rio for small viewmodels and Tibet for the more complex ones.

But if you want to have a more homogeneous code, you can apply Tibet throughout the project.

I have already worked on projects where we only use Tibet and everything is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I End up doing this, but I'm not sure it's a proper way. If any one know a better way to do ti m please feel free to post it.

```
    public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _description, _setdescription;

    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
                   set => SetProperty(ref _description, value);

    }

    public string SetDescription
    {
        get => _setdescription;
        set => SetProperty(ref _setdescription, value);

    }



    public MvxCommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new MvxCommand(SetValueCommand);
    }

    private void SetValueCommand()
    {

        SetDescription = Description;
        Description = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and this my axml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:MvxBind="Text SetDescription"
    android:text=""
    />

<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    app:MvxBind="Text Description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    android:text="Set Data"
    app:MvxBind="Click MyCommand"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)